# How to prevent previous view from showing when the browser back button is hit in Laravel 8

Tags: routes, laravel-8

I have 2 views named feedbackForm and feedbackThankYou.Once the feedback form is submitted I want to show the feedbackThankYou view.Till now everything is working fine but as soon I hit the back button in the browser it takes me to the feedbackForm view. But I donot want to show it once it is submitted.

```
public function submitFeedback(Request $request, CustomerFeedbackRepository $customerFeedbackRepo){
            $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'rating' => 'required|integer|min:1|max:5',
                'comments' => 'required|string|max:255',
            ]);
        
            if ($validator->fails()) {
                return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
            }
    
            $data["user_id"] = $request["user_id"];
            $data["customer_id"] = $request["customer_id"];
            $data["rating"] = $request["rating"];
            $data["comment"] = $request["comments"];
    
            $customerFeedbackRepo->create($data);
            
            return view('feedbackThankYou');
    }
```